# Bash always returning error code eq 0

Tags: bash

I was I am trying to check if a folder is part of a git or svn repository.
I use the following command to get that and store the error code in a variable.

```
RSVN=`svn status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
RGIT=`git status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
```

The thing is I am always getting 0 as error code.

I try it in the command line and I get the expected result

```
user@host trunk$ svn status &> /dev/null;
user@host  trunk$ echo $?
0
user@host  trunk$ git status &> /dev/null;
user@host  trunk$ echo $?
128
```

but when I run the script I get :

```
+ + svn status

+ echo 0
+ RSVN=0
M       buildpackage
+ git status
+
+ echo 0
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /build)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
+ RGIT=0
```

The way this called is as subscript.
It is callled by an othe script.

first script

```
#!/bin/sh -x
#set -e

#do stuf 

. ../../../tools/second_script.sh
```

second script

```
#!/bin/sh -x
set -e

#do stuf 

RSVN=`svn status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
RGIT=`git status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
```

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try without `&` and see whether it works as expected?

Comment: Works for me. I’m afraid we need to see your script.

Comment: I didn't , but I try it and I get the same result.

Comment: Could you be more exact where you get zero-status? With `set -e` your scripts would stop on first non-zero exit status.

Comment: @simno There is a trace output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is being substituted by the shell **before** the command is executed. Do this instead:

```
svn status &> /dev/null; RSVN=$?
git status &> /dev/null; RGIT=$?
```

Actually, get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll say `PATH=$(something)` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: It maskes sense, but I still get 0 on both, and with `set -e` if one command fails it will exit my script. I am probably doing something wrong.
The `$?` dont seem to work well inside a script.
I made a litle work arround for now.

Comment: You answer is correct, I try it without `set -e` flag it with works.
what did was  `set +e` before and `set -e` and it works fine.
Tanks I will mark it as the good answer.

Comment: Yes, thats what `set -e` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I follow an other aproch for now, this does what I need, but is a worst solution than using exit codes.

insted of:

```
RSVN=`svn status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
RGIT=`git status &> /dev/null; echo $?`
```

Use :

```
RSVN=`svn status 2>&1 | grep "is not a working copy" | wc -l`
RGIT=`git status 2>&1 | grep "Not a git repository"  | wc -l`
```